# Django - Is there a weekly calendar widget similar to when2meet.com?

Tags: django, calendar, widget

I'm trying to create an application that allows a user to set a weekly schedule of when they would be available to meet. Once these set weekly schedules have been made, it would then be set to unavailable once a customer's proposal to meet is approved by the user.

Comment: I think you need to use a bit of javascript, there are plenty of javascript calendar libraries. for example https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

Comment: I see. What would possibly be the necessary steps for the back-end side in terms of storing the data of the available and available dates?